# LessJs file not being processed in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less

I'm experiencing a peculiar issue and I'm having trouble diagnosing it.

I am using LessJs in an ASP.NET MVC web application and the less file is not being processed and I am seeing my variables in the "F12" debug tools -- and the style is not applied as expected as a bi-product.

The markup looks like this.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/site.less" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/less-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am seeing the files correctly delivered to the browser (from Network tab)

[image: Network Traffic]

There are NO errors in the console.

but when I inspect my element, I see this:

[image: CSS error in Browser]

The styles from `bootstrap.css` are applied as expected.

Am I missing a step?  I've used less with ASP.NET before, this one's got me stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: I see that there is frendly which propably should be friendly.
Didn't you change the file accidentally?

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki -- good catch.  its actually wrong in both places haha.  but the point is that you shouldn't see it at all once the content is delivered to the browser, its supposed to be parsed and replaced with an hex representation of a color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  This issue was that the link tag that references the less files had an incorrect `rel` attribute.  For less it should be `stylesheet/less` as opposed to just `stylesheet`, which is used for CSS.

```
<link href="~/Content/site.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
```